# Have an idea but I am not sure how to go about it and if django alone would be enough?

Tags: python, django

I technically have 2 questions that I am combining into 1 post.

- In views we can run python stuff just as usual right? So how
  demanding a thing can I put in a view. Say I had some game made using
  pygame and PyOpenGL(3D). Can I put that in a view and expect it to
  work or do I need to do something additional to it because it is
  going to end up on a website and I need to know much I can stress
  django. The other part of the question is that, would it be dependent
  on the server django is being hosted on. Can I make it client sided
  (or is it so by default, knowing how powerful django is, I would
  expect it to be so). I know some part of this question is quite a bit
  'noobish' but I am technically noob when it comes to django. All I
  have done is build one website with some forms and stuff (Basic
  beginner stuff). But now I am interested in stepping things up!
- The other thing is most of my projects and games that I run is on git
  hub and I have recently considered to use git version control along
  with github. So when I run something, is there way where I can tell
  django to get a repo of my github and run that in a view. I know its 
  quite a cool yet complex idea, especially for a beginner you would
  expect me to start progressing with something more modest, but I want
  scalability and thought this was a good approach to what I wanted to 
  achieve.

As always, I am thankful and greatful for all your suggestions!

Comment: "I technically have 2 questions that I am combining into 1 post." Please don't do this. We don't have "posts" here, we have "questions". [Ask one thing at a time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/39224/248627), _especially_ when they're _completely_ unrelated as they are here.

Comment: Also, when you post a question please make sure it's on-topic (you can read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]). Neither of these questions is on-topic: the first is far too broad, and the second is completely unclear. Why would you want a running application to grab code from GitHub and run it? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: And whoever upvoted this question should _stop_. Mouse over the upvote button and read the tooltip: "This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear". Upvoting isn't for "I feel sorry for somebody whose question has been downvoted".

Comment: What can I say? I am new too this platform and was not aware of its rules.

Comment: It seems, I have broken a rule by not taking the tour, I am sorry and will not commit such a mistake again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: **No, and probably not a good practice**

First of all, Chris is correct in that you are using StackOverflow poorly. Questions must be confined to one single topic and not be multiple different topics. Besides, had you asked two different questions and tagged them correctly, you would get better answers.

Question 1:

The `view` in Django is not what is shown to your user. The `template` is. The template is made of HTML and JavaScript. The view just does the mechanics of filling out the template.

I am not that familiar with PyGame, but I (and the few minutes of Googling I spent) tell me that it is not easy to even port the game to HTML/Javascript manually, yet alone run a Python game in the web browser through some kind of interpreter.

Question 2:

Your second question is interesting (and one I think you should ask separately with more detail). I would bet that it would be possible with careful automated scripting of the deployment process, but of questionable scalability. It also would be more vulnerable to malicious attack as then the single failure point is the repo.

It really does depend on your use case though.

Comment: Sorry, I have mostly been using reddit for most of my life and had recently come across stack overflow. So I am not well versed with the rules of stack overflow. Your first part of your answer does not surprise as I had a feeling it might be the case and some research on pointed on that direction although, I was still not sure of this though. The second part was what I was going to do if the first part was possible, but since it isn't I will look at some other alternatives!